# java Socket is not connected: connect

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, httpsurlconnection

I have this piece of code that would allow me to connect to an url (example: https://www.google.fr/)

```
URL urlSP = new URL("https://www.google.fr/");
HttpsURLConnection connSP = (HttpsURLConnection) urlSP.openConnection();        
connSP.connect();
```

when I run the code I get this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:200)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1123)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at sms.main(sms.java:118)
```

I do not know if it's caused by the  proxy but I tried this code

```
     System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy");
     System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "port");
     System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "user");
     System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "password ")
```

but it does not work either

Someone has an answer please?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to call `connSP.connect()` at all. After calling `urlSP.openConnection()` to get `connSP`, simply call `connSP.getInputStream()` and read from it as needed. Alternatively, you can use `urlSP.openStream()` instead, which calls `openConnection().getInputStream()` for you.

Comment: thank you for your response .

Comment: I have removed connSP.connect() , it works with the method GET but when i set  
connSP.setRequestMethod("POST");  
connSP.setDoInput(true) to send parameteres needed for the connection .
connSP.getInputStream() ;

I hava this error : 
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name

Comment: I have the same problem when i try : 
connSP.getResponseCode () ;  

I need to know if the connection has been made or not , and also to recperate a token of authentification  received in response if the connection is well done.
Have you any idea please ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: when using Post, are you calling `getOutputStream()` and writing to it, before reading from `getInputStream()`? There are TONS of examples and tutorials on how to use `URLConnection`, I would be surprised if you can't find one that works for you.